# Place a Javascript API Google Map with iFrame

Tags: javascript, html

I need to place a Google Map made using Javascript API within an iFrame so that I can perform operations on the map and then submit a form that I create below that takes values from the map, for example, the latitude and longitude. How can I make that happen?

```
<script>
          var map;
          var circle=null;
          myLatlng = {lat: 28.713956, lng: 77.006653};
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: myLatlng,
              zoom: 13
            });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Click to zoom'
            });

          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
              document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
              document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
              marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            });
          }
</script>
```

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my-API-key>&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Also, I need to process the data coming from the map, so I don't want to use Google Maps Embed API. I know it can be placed in an iFrame using it. I have tried doing that but that is not what I need.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places This will help you